# Getting Unique ID foe a maximum amount grouped by days in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I have this query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  max(amount) as money,
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP(time), '%j') as day 
FROM  table 
GROUP BY day
```

The console shows an error as it wants the ID to the group by clause but if i add ID in the group by it will get many ID for a specific day.
I want to print a unique ID with the maximum amount in a specific day.

For ex:

```
ID: 1    Money:123     Day:365
```

Answer (score 0):

not clear from the question, but looks like you already have only one entry per given id for particular day. Assuming this, below query does what you need

```
SELECT id, amount, day
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, amount, day,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY day ORDER BY amount DESC) AS win
  FROM dataset.table
)
WHERE win = 1
```

in case if above assumption is wrong (so you have multiple entries for the same id for same day), use below

```
SELECT id, amount, day
FROM (
  SELECT id, amount, day,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY day ORDER BY amount DESC) AS win
  FROM (
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS amount, day
    FROM dataset.table
    GROUP BY id, day
  )
)
WHERE win = 1
```